# array_intersect() Argument is not an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have developed this small code to check if 2 text, one from a database and the other from an outside imput have common words.
The problem is that I get a message "Argument is not an array".
I cannot see where is the problem.
I also need to check if the 2 messages if should have the same words are in the same sequence.
Please help to understand where is the mistake.
Thanks

```
$checkMsg=strip_tags($_POST['checkMsg']); // message from input form
$message // message from database
$MsgWords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $checkMsg);
if(!empty($checkMsg)){
         foreach ($MsgWords as $Neword)
      {           $Neword = trim($Neword);

          echo " $Neword";
      }
          $word = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $message);

      foreach ($word as $currentWord)
             {
                                      $currentWord = trim($currentWord);

                 echo "  $currentWord"; 
            }


            $intersect=array_intersect( $Neword ,
                                        $currentWord);
                    echo" Your common words are: $intersect";}else{echo "No common words";}
```

Comment: $neword and $currentword are just strings. you're not intersecting arrays at all. So ... big surprise... PHP tells you this.

Comment: I hope you know what array is.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said you're comparing the strings not the array. Your code should be something like this (you'll have to probably change this a little its just an example)

```
$checkMsg=strip_tags($_POST['checkMsg']); // message from input form
$message // message from database
$MsgWords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $checkMsg);
if(!empty($checkMsg)){
     $intersect=array_intersect($message,$MsgWords);
     if (count($intersect)>1) {
     //only show output if there are matches
       echo "Words in common are:<br />";
       foreach ($intersect as $Neword) { 
          $Neword = trim($Neword);
          echo $Neword."<br />";
       }
     } else {
       echo "There are no words in common";
     }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so firstly you're looping through the two arrays and changing the value, but the way you have it, you are just changing a temp copy of the value, not the value in the array. To do that, you need to use the `&` sign in the `foreach()` to tell it to use a reference variable in the loop, like this:

```
foreach ($MsgWords as &$Neword) {  //added the & sign here.
    $Neword = trim($Neword);
}
```

Do the same thing to the other `foreach()` loop too.

Secondly, your `array_intersect()` call is looking at the single strings, not at the whole arrays. You need it to look at the arrays:

```
//your incorrect version:
$intersect=array_intersect( $Neword, $currentWord);

//corrected version, using your variable names.
$intersect=array_intersect( $MsgWords, $word);
```

That should solve your problems.

[EDIT]

Also, note the `array_intersect()` outputs an array (ie the array of the intersection between the two input arrays). You can't use `echo()` to print an array directly. If you try, it will just show the word 'Array'. You need to convert it into a string first:

```
//your incorrect code.
echo "Your common words are: $intersect";

//corrected code:
echo "Your common words are: ".implode(',',$intersect);
```

I would also note that your coding style is *very* messy and hard to read. I strongly recommend trying to tidy it up; follow some kind of indentation and variable naming rules. Otherwise it will be very hard to maintain.

Comment: I did the changes suggested but the out put say: "Your common words are: Array".unfortunatly similar solution I had before.

Comment: @user2087642 - you suggestions were correct; I've made an edit to show you the problem you still have. But these issues are a sign that you really haven't got a very strong understanding of PHP or how arrays work. I suggest taking some time to learn how these things work before trying to use them.